# how to obtain data values individually while plotting graph using flot

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, flot

I am drawing a bar chart like this [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/WnC9B/)

Now the data is given like this

```
  data : [ [ 1, 85], [ 2, 50 ], [ 3, 18], [ 4, 8 ] ]
```

I need to know how will i be able to access this 85,50,18,8 individually.So that when i take my cursor to the bar chart and click it then it show me the respective values.

It should be something like `series.data.` 
But i don't know how to get the values.

Comment: So basically, what you want to know is what value is associated with the clicked area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is simply:

```
// in plotclick handler - to get Y axis value for clicked item
obj.series.data[obj.dataIndex][1]
```

`obj.dataIndex` is index of the point in the data array (which in turn is available as `obj.series.data`).

Here's working example http://jsfiddle.net/WnC9B/24/

---

This answer has been sponsored by http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt ;)